# Getting XSLT to render an HTML5 doctype in Firefox

Tags: html, xslt, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an XSLT stylesheet to output clean(ish) HTML5, which is then being styled with Bootstrap.

To work in IE8 (unfortunately required) it needs a proper

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

header, which is being rendered via the

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xml:text>
```

hack. However, Firefox (22 in case it's relevant) is rendering the DOCTYPE to the user.

Does anyone know a better way to sort this that'll work cross-browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "proper" (non-hacky) way of [rendering HTML5 with XSLT](http://ukchill.com/technology/generating-html5-using-xslt/).

```
<xsl:output
     method="xml"
     doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
     encoding="UTF-8"
     indent="yes" />
```

Comment: Thanks, just found that on another question here too. Much obliged!